# Dynamic javascript jSon built form not submitting through ajax - Phonegap

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am attempting my first Phonegap app - and my first AJAX calls.

I have an xmlhttp request returning JSON provided by ColdFusion. It dynamically builds a form. This works great. But when I try to submit that form via AJAX - for an onscreen refresh, it doesn't work. Either the form doesn't submit (as below) or if I change the "button" to "submit" - it leaves the page and goes to the link which is not what I want.

Can I do an AJAX send on a dynamic form like this? Or is there another way I should be building this form? Not sure what the protocol is...

```js
<div id="simple-msg"></div>

<script>
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "http://flightderby.bigfatdev.com/phonegap/Instant_Game_Create.cfm";

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        myFunction(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
 
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();

function myFunction(response) {
    var arr = JSON.parse(response);
    var i;
    var out = "<form name='instantRaceForm' id='instantRaceForm' method='post' action='http://www.bigfatdev.com/phonegap1/GetUsers.cfm'><div id='InstantGameFlightList'><ul>";

    for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    
  out += "<li><div class='IconSelector'><input name='ChosenWinner' type='radio' value='" +
arr[i].ChosenWinner +
"' id='ChosenWinner_" +
arr[i].ChosenWinner +
"'  /><label for='ChosenWinner_" +
arr[i].ChosenWinner +
"'><div class='" +
arr[i].Icon +
"'></div></label><div class='IG_Payout'>" +
arr[i].FractionOdds + 
"- 1</div></div><div class='Details'><div class='Airline'>" +
arr[i].Airline +
"</div><div class='FlightNumber'>Flight " +
arr[i].FlightNumber +
"</div><div>From: " +
arr[i].FromAirport +
"</div><div>To: " +
arr[i].ToAirport +
"</div><div>Flight Time: " +
arr[i].FlightTime +
"</div></div></li>";
  
  
    }
    out += "</ul><input name='Case' id='Case'  type='hidden' value='Submit' /><input type='button'  id='simple-post' value='Place Wager!' class='ActionBtn' /></div></form>"
    document.getElementById("simple-msg").innerHTML = out;
}

</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
 
  $('#simple-menu').sidr();

 $("#simple-post").click(function()
 {
  $("#instantRaceForm").submit(function(e)
  {
   $("#simple-msg").html("<img src='img/loading-blue.gif' style='width:30px; height30px;'/>");
   var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
   var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
   $.ajax(
   {
    url : formURL,
    type: "POST",
    data : postData,
    success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) 
    {
     $("#simple-msg").html('<pre><code class="prettyprint">'+data+'</code></pre>');
 
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
    {
     $("#simple-msg").html('<pre><code class="prettyprint">AJAX Request Failed<br/> textStatus='+textStatus+', errorThrown='+errorThrown+'</code></pre>');
    }
   });
   e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action
   e.unbind();
  });
   
  $("#instantRaceForm").submit(); //SUBMIT FORM
 });
  
});

</script>
```

Comment: You are already working with jQuerys $.ajax... Why are you building a plain ajax call too?!?

Comment: Well.. mostly because I am new to this and I am not exactly sure I know what to do... Following various tutorials... Piecing it together with what little I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are doing ajax, then you don't want a regular form submission.

You've done the right thing with `e.preventDefault()`, then ruin that good work by submitting it anyway, doh!

Delete the line :

```
$("#instantRaceForm").submit(); //SUBMIT FORM
```

and change the button to `type="submit"`

Another issue ... the form doesn't exist at the time you attempt to attach the submit handler, therefore it will have no effect. This can be overcome by "delegating" submission handling to an ancestor element - eg `document`- as follows :

```
$(document).on('click', "#simple-post", function() {
    ...
});
```

Comment: I made the changes - but it is the same result - it directs the form to a new page - redirects to the Form Action - rather than staying within the page.  ??

Comment: Right, I've added something.

Comment: That helped! It is now grabbing the JSON.